# Does x509 have an "issued at" timestamp? Can you tell when an x509 certificate was issued?

Tags: x.509, timestamp, time

The [JWT Spec (RFC 7519)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.6) has an issued at field ("iat"). Does x509 have any analogous value? I see a [Validity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.5) field, but nothing else time related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X.509 has a `Not Before` and a `Not After` field which describes when the certificate is valid to use for the defined purpose. The `Not Before` usually matches about the time when the certificate was issued but it is not required to do so.

Comment: It sounds like the distinction was not made or not considered important for x509's purposes when it was written.

Answer (score 1):

RFC 5280 does not provide a distinct field specifying the issuance date of a certificate.

If you really need that information though, you can check a *Certificate Transparency* logs for that certificate. They are not necessarily perfect either, but they give you a definitive *issuedNotAfter* time. Take the logs for [the current google.com](https://crt.sh/?q=29%3ABF%3AC8%3A42%3A8B%3AF2%3A3F%3AFB%3AA3%3AC0%3A43%3AD7%3A33%3ABB%3A33%3A22%3ABA%3A6A%3ADC%3A61) certificate. The certificate states a notBefore date of *Dec 13 13:51:18 2017 GMT*, while the CT timestamp indicates that the certificate was probably signed about 40 minutes after that date.